# Bode plot of LTSPICE

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply

I would like to know how to use LTSPIC to measure the bode plot of the below circuit.
Transfer function = Y/X
Could someone give me some suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What LTSpice support or forum sites have you been on to that didn't give you this answer? [Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: For the shown circuit no simulation program will be able to produce a meaningful result. The reason: The first opamp will have no operational point within the linear amplification range because there is no DC feedback.

Comment: Note, to get around that for simulation, put a 1MEG resistor across Cb.

Comment: @LvW If the circuit would have been exactly as seen, nothing else, yes, that would be true. But SPICE engines get around that problem by adding some key parallel resistance across the feedback capacitor, behind the curtains. So it will work, but then...

Comment: ... EEC, you already have there a `.MEAS` script that is meant to measure something in an `.AC` analysis. So then how come you can't get it to simulate? Either you're not telling everything, or you just grabbed a picture from somewhere else and tha tis not your circuit. Also, if you'll open up the manual you'll see exactly what steps to follow. Or see some tutorial, because what you're asking is very basic usage -- if you don't know it, then you have to learn it (otherwise how do you plan to use the software further?).

Comment: @a concerned citizen , since more than 25 years I work with PSpice and TopSpice, and I am sure that nothing happens "behind the curtains". A capacitor is a capacitor - unless I am using a specialized model for C.

Comment: Nothing wrong in simulating an integrating stage but it is true that it can be tedious to fine-tune the input bias to set the output of the first op-amp within its operating rails. As I shown below, a simple external auto-bias circuit does the job well and the ac response is delivered seamlessly.

Comment: @LvW Check the `gfarad` parameter in the [`.options` section of LTspice help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0EWH.png).  This is an LTspice unique "feature", though, and it was undocumented in previous versions.  @aconcernedcitizen I cannot find something similar in the ngspice source code, so it's possible and/or likely other SPICE engines do not have this.

Comment: @Ste Kulov. I am not using LTSpice (only PSpice and TopSpice). Therefore, I am not aware of these options LTSpice seems to offer.

Comment: @LvW I know.  I explicitly said it was unique to LTspice, and likely not elsewhere.  I was just pointing out an example of things happening "behind the curtains", and in the software the questioner is specifically asking about.  Please ignore it if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this circuit featuring an origin pole and a high open-loop gain is to inject an ac modulation in which the dc bias sets the op-amps outputs in a linear range, e.g. 2-3 V for instance. With the divider values, this is a 400-V dc bias but it needs to be exactly meeting the value preventing the op-amps from railing up or down, with a few µV of resolution. The below circuit does the job for you and provides the exact bias for a 3-V or so output:

[image]

The trick is using the CoL/LoL filter. Before running the ac analysis, SPICE, which is a linear solver, will run a dc operating point. Doing so, it opens all caps. and shorts inductors. In this mode, the extra "op-amp" E3 closes the loop in dc and makes sure the output is around 3 V (it has a 60-dB gain in this example hence the static error) but the absolute value does not have a real importance as long as you stay away from ground and the upper \$V_{cc}\$ rail. Then, as ac injection starts via CoL, the LC filter forms an extremely low-frequency low-pass filter which physically opens the loop in ac and lets you sweep the circuit. I used this technique for years when analyzing averaged models of switching circuit to maintain adequate operating point while ac-sweeping the circuit. I think I learned the technique while reading Dr. Vince Bello's papers back in 1996. A simple .AC DEC 100 1m 1k will then instruct the engine to deliver the Bode plot you need.

Comment: Yes - what you have demonstrated (auto-bias) is a special case of the following arrangement: A real opamp (model) without a DC-stabilizing resistive feedback (e.g. ideal Miller integrator) cannot find a stable DC bias point - unless it is part of an overall (larger) negative feedback loop.

Comment: Servus LvW. I would point two differences: in simulation, even with an extremely-high gain, I can find a stable point because the bias is fixed and there are no drifts. If I bias the input of the simulated circuit at a 399.996-V level (without the auto-bias) then I have 2.5 V in the output and the ac response is ok. On the bench, if I try to do that with a high-\$A_{ol}\$ op-amp, it is likely to fail because of noise, offsets drifts with temp which will make the amp rail up or down very quickly.

Comment: Servus Verbal Kint. Yes - I understand (and agree, of course).